Old wooden cross puzzle
I have a couple of wood puzzles that my grandad made. Not sure when he made them but he was born in 1896. I believe he was involved in the manufacture of wooden propellers for First World War aeroplanes. One of these puzzles, the simpler one, is disassembled.  How can it be reassembled?


Well, google it by pictures "wooden 6 part puzzle"

These are known as Burr puzzles, maybe it's one of the designs pictured on Wikipedia.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

It has a key piece (second from the left, no notches) so it should be a fairly easy version. It is not quite the standard classic one pictured on Wikipedia though (the rightmost piece is not used in the classic one, it is not a notchable piece)

I don't have time to write up a solution now. If you number the pieces in the picture 1 to 6 from left to right, then they should be paired up as 1+5, 4+6, 2+3, each pair is parallel, and perpendicular to the other pairs.
